# Using model binding with a tree object and recursive rendering in Razor pages?

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages, model-binding

I have this class:

```
public class SmartNode
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public JsonValueKind ValueKind { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinal { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public SmartNode ParentNode { get; set; }
    public List<SmartNode> SubNodes { get; set; } = new List<SmartNode>();
}
```

`IsFinal` means that the object represents a simple JSON node (string, boolean or number..) if `IsFinal` is false, I do recursion to get the "final" properties:

and here's the razor page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@{
    if (Model.HeadNode != null)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            await DrawNode(Model.HeadNode);

            async Task DrawNode(SmartNode node)
            {
                var margin = (node.Level * 20).ToString() + "px";
                if (!node.IsFinal)
                {
                    <h4 style="margin-left:@margin">@node.Key</h4>
                    foreach (var subnode in node.SubNodes)
                    {
                        await DrawNode(subnode);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    int i = 0;//temp
                    var id = node.Key + "_" + node.Level;
                    <div>
                        <label for="@id" style="margin-left: @margin">@node.Key</label>
                        @switch (node.ValueKind)
                        {
                            case System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.Undefined:
                                break;
                            case System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.Object:
                                break;
                            case System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.Array:
                                break;
                            case System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.String:
    
                                <input type="text" name="???.Value" value="@node.Value" id="@id" />
                                break;
                            case System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.Number:
                                <input type="number" name="???.Value" value="@node.Value" id="@id" />

                                break;
                            case System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.True:
                            case System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.False:
                                <input type="checkbox" name="???.Value"
                                       checked="@(node.Value.ToString() == "True")"
                                       value="True" id="@id" />
                                <input name="???.Value" type="hidden" value="False">
                                break;
                            case System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.Null:
                                <input type="text" name="???.Value" value="@node.Value" id="@id" />
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    </div>
                }

            }

            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is how can I assign the input name from razor

I use .NET 5 Razor Pages.

Comment: Couldn't you get rid of `IsFinal` and just use `SubNodes.Count() == 0` instead?

Comment: Yes, I could, but I didn't think of it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this directly on the page, create a component that does the rendering, pass the node to the component, and make the component contain instances of itself for each child node.

Congratz now you have a recursive component.

Edit1: The component (Here SmartTreeView.razor) would look something like this:

```
<!-- Maybe some title per node, whatever -->
<h3>@Node.Key - @Node.Value</h3>

<!-- Render node data here, like -->
@if (Node.Value != null)
{
    <DataComponent data="@(Node.Value)" />
}

<!-- Then, recursion -->
@foreach (var node in Node.SubNodes)
{
    <span>@tab</span>
    <SmartTreeView Node="@(node)" />
}



@code {
    private const string tab = "\t";

    [Parameter]
    public SmartNode Node { get; set; }

}
```

Then the page just puts `<SmartTreeView Node="@(Model.HeadNode)" />` wherever.

Comment: Do you mean [view-components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0)?

Comment: Yes, you would include it like `<vc:custom-tree root="Model.HeadNode"></vc:custom-tree>`

Comment: shouldn't I send the current node, not the entire tree? , ex: `root:"node"`, but I suppose it's not possible sending objects to VC

Comment: Your page has only one node: The root or in your case HeadNode. The recursion occurs only in the component.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I tried to put your suggestion in code but it didn't work, what I've ended up with, is the same result without the view component.
I didn't understand "and make the component contain instances of itself for each child node"

Comment: Here's my implementation of the component view: :https://github.com/mshwf/JsonDataTreeVisualizer/blob/viewcomponent/Pages/Shared/Components/TreeDrawer/Default.cshtml

Comment: I added the recursive component too add to the page. Can maybe add the page later.

Comment: What you have in your else would go into `DataComponent.razor` or something.

Comment: and how do get the Node value after submitting the form in OnPost handler?

Comment: I'm calling it like this: @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<JsonDataTreeVisualizer.Components.SmartTreeView>(RenderMode.Static, new { Node = Model.HeadNode }))
other options didn't work

Comment: Not sure about the whole submit/request stuff, just know about how to separate concerns and do razor syntax^^

Comment: But that's not my question! I don't have a problem with rendering. The problem is submitting a recursive model.